# Animating a range slider back and forth (loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, range

I am trying to animate a range slider that slides to the max and down to the minimum over a duration of about 2 seconds for each movement and in increments of 1. I do not want to it to be instantaneous; I want the user to see the slider go back and forth. Here is my current code:

```
var slider = $("#battleslider").slider({
animate: 900
});

$('#move').click(function(){
slider.slider('value', slider.slider('value') + 500);
slider.slider('value', slider.slider('value') - 500);
});
```

The problem is that when the browser loads and the button is activated, the slider is nearly instantaneously at the max and then decreases for the proper duration. I also need the slide to go change in increments of 1 so that the user can get exactly what the position is. However to do that I would need a loop and this basically causes my browser (Chrome) to freeze up.

Any alternative methods or anything else would be great!

I hope this makes sense and let me know if any more clarification is needed.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5j2f0L2t/1/

Comment: Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Sorry, took me a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/5j2f0L2t/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you just use css3 (and javascript/jQuery) for this. You can set an animation using css3 [animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and the rest of the functionality can be added when needed.

I created and example [here](http://codepen.io/Titulum/pen/jPwNoJ).

```
@keyframes slide
{
  0% { left: 10px; }
  50% { left: 160px; }
  100% { left: 10px; }
}

#slider
{
   animation-name: slide;
   animation-duration: 2s;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-delay: 1s; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and example! With this code, I will also be able to get the exact value of the slider at a certain moment in time, not just its destination. It looks that way, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: No problem, check out all the [possibilities of css3 animation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp) for even more information.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put a question mark there. I mean will be able to get the exact value of the slider at a certain moment in time? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I [updated the pen](http://codepen.io/Titulum/pen/jPwNoJ). By using the "offsetLeft" property, you can get the coordinates at any moment Click the red button to make it move.